# Whats the word for an missed event?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I am looking for a fitting end to this sentence:

With so many members around I refrained from speaking up and now my wish/plan to have a private conversation with the leader remains ______________ ( *a distant dream* )

Kindly suggest me the suitable phrase to fit in blanks.

### EDIT

I would like to add that the missed event is not like 'once in a lifetime event' in the sense there will be more such opportunity in future (maybe a couple of months/years later).

Comment: Is the verb "remains" a requirement? Or can it be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meaning #2 of "[unfulfilled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unfulfilled)" would work, especially if you still have hopes that it will/can eventually happen:

2. not having achieved one's potential or **desires**

Answer (score 4):

[Out of reach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+reach)  would fill the blank well.

> 1. Lit. not near enough to be reached or touched.
>
> Place the cookies out of reach, or the children will eat them all.
>
> 2. Fig. unattainable.
>
> I wanted to be president, but I'm afraid that such a goal is out of
>   reach.

Answer (score 3):

... ***a lost [opportunity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=opportunity&allowed_in_frame=0)*** implies a general disappointment:

> late 14c., from Old French opportunite (13c.) and directly from Latin
>   opportunitatem (nominative opportunitas) "fitness, convenience,
>   suitableness, favorable time,"
>
> from opportunus (see [opportune](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=opportune&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> c.1400, from Old French opportun and directly from Latin opportunus
>   "fit, convenient, suitable, favorable,"
>
> from the phrase ob portum veniens "coming toward a port," in reference
>   to the wind,
>
> from ob "to, toward" (see ob-) + portus "harbor" (see port (n.1)).

**missed**, **misplaced**, and **blown** can replace *lost* with increasing levels of self-reproach.

---

If you wanted to employ a metaphor, you could use ***a ship lost at sea***

---

...**a [*chimera*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chimera)** would put it **way** out of reach:

> A thing that is hoped or wished for but in fact is illusory or
>   impossible to achieve:
>
> cited from oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: hmmm. Chimera too heavily connotes "a monster from Greek mythology that breathes fire and has a lion's head, a goat's body, and a snake's tail" (from the Merriam Webster def #1)

Comment: Isn't chimaera - reminiscent of a grotesque product of the imagination.

Comment: You are referring to the legitimate connotation of the original meaning, which has migrated slightly.

Answer (score 3):

See if "**unrealised**" can fit in the blanks.

> Adj. -unrealized dreams and ambitions.
>
> With so many members around I refrained from speaking up and now my
>   wish/plan to have a private conversation with the leader remains
>   *[unrealized](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unrealised)*.

Comment: I didn't know this word exists. The meaning suits the sentence but I feel a bit of awkwardness saying it ( maybe because I'm using it for the first time), unfulfilled sounds more neutral to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think *[wishful thinking](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wishful+thinking)* may fit in your contest:

> - thinking in which what one wishes were the case is believed to be real or likely to become real.